# How can I detect 64-bit build support for iOS in continuous integration?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

We recently submitted a build of our mobile application and then realized that we forgot to build it with 64-bit support, which has been required in the App Store for a fairly long time.

This is easy enough to fix. It would be nice if we could catch this in our continuous integration build pipeline, however.

For this specific case, we may be able to get away with a grep command that verifies `arm64` support is included in the `pbxproj` file.

Slightly more generally, is there a static analysis tool that would let us query the project settings files more systematically in our continuous integration pipeline? Is this, for instance, something you could detect using [fastlane actions](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#project)?